# Passport.js - req.user is undefined on some routes and defined on others

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using Passport.js for authentication in a MEAN stack application. On some routes the `req.user` object is defined and working just fine, on other routes, it is not defined and isAuthenticated gives false all the time.

This is how Passport is setup in my app.

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    async    = require('async'),
    crypto   = require('crypto'),
    User = require('../models/RegisteredUser'),
    Business   = require('../models/Business'),
    nodemailer = require("nodemailer"),
    configAuth = require('../../config/auth'),

    xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');


let AuthController =
{
    // ============================
    //             HOME PAGE
    // ============================
    home: function(req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs');
    },

    // ============================
    //              LOGIN
    // ============================
    getLoginFail: function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.flash('loginMessage'));
    },


  getLoginSuccess: function(req, res) {
    req.session.save(function() {
      res.redirect('/'); 
    })
  },

    postLogin: function(req, res){
    passport.authenticate('local-login', {
        successRedirect : '/auth/successLogIn',
        failureRedirect : '/auth/failLogIn',

        failureFlash : true
    })(req, res);},

    // ============================
    //           SIGNUP
    // ============================
    getSignupFail: function(req, res) {
        res.json(req.flash('signupMessage'));
    },


  getSignupSuccess: function(req, res) {
        res.json("success");
    },


    postSignup: function(req, res){

    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
        successRedirect : '/auth/successSignUp',
        failureRedirect : '/auth/failSignUp',

        failureFlash : true
    })(req, res);},




    // ============================
    //      PROFILE SECTION
    // ============================
    getProfile: function(req, res){
        if (req.isAuthenticated())
        {
            if(req.user.user_type == 1)       // regular user
            {
        res.redirect('/');
        // res.render('user_profile.ejs', {
        // user : req.user, bookings: req.user.bookings, subscriptions: req.user.subscriptions });
            }
            else if(req.user.user_type == 2)  // business
            {
        res.render('business_profile.ejs', {
          user : req.user });
            }
            else if(req.user.user_type == 3)  // admin
            {
                res.render('admin_profile.ejs', {
                user : req.user});
            }
        }
        else
    {
            res.redirect('/');
    }
    },

    // =====================================
    //                   LOGOUT
    // =====================================
    logout: function(req, res) {

        req.session.destroy(function (err) {
      if(err) return res.status(500).json("error");

      req.logout();
      res.json("successful");

  });
    },
    // =====================================
    //                  FACEBOOK
    // =====================================
    facebookLogin   : function(req, res){
        passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' })(req, res);},


    facebookCallback: function(req, res,next){
    passport.authenticate('facebook', function(err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          if (!user) { return res.json("Error! Please go back to http://localhost:8000 to try and sign in again."); }
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            req.session.save(function(){
              res.redirect("http://localhost:8000/");
           });
          });
        })(req, res);


        },






    // =====================================
    //                  GOOGLE
    // =====================================
    googleLogin : function(req, res){
        passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] })(req, res);
    },

  googleCallback: function(req, res){
    passport.authenticate('google', function(err, user, info) {
          if (err) { return next(err); }
          if (!user) { return res.json("error"); }
          req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            req.session.save(function(){
             return res.redirect("http://localhost:8000/");
           });
          });
        })(req, res);


        },


    // =====================================
    //           FORGOT PASSWORD
    // =====================================
    getForgetPassword: function(req, res){
        res.render('frogetPassword.ejs');
    },
//same email problem
    forgotPassword: function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.body.email){

        async.waterfall([
      // generate random token of length 20, to uniquely identify each request of reseting password
        function(done) {
        crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
            var token = buf.toString('hex');
            done(err, token);
          });
        },
      // validate the entered email belongs to some actual user saved in the database
      // first, search the business collection
        function(token, done) {
        var check = 0;
        Business.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, business){
              if(err)
              {
                  console.log("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
                  return res.json("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
              }
              if(!business)
              {
                check++;
                if(check == 2)    // if no user found, print error msg and redirect
                {
                console.log('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
                return res.json("No account with that email address exists.");
                }
              }
              // if found, set the values of resetPasswordToken to the token generated
              else
               {
                 business.local.resetPasswordToken = token;
                 business.local.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;    // expires after one hour
                 business.save(function(err){

                 done(err, token, business);
              });
            }
        });
        // then search the registeredusers collection
            User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
            if(err)
              {
                  console.log("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
                  return res.json("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
              }
            if (!user) {
            check++;
            if(check == 2)       // if no user found, print error msg and redirect
            {
              console.log('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
              return res.json("No account with that email address exists.");
            }

            }
          // if found, set the values of resetPasswordToken to the token generated
          else
          {
               user.local.resetPasswordToken = token;
               user.local.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000;   // expires after one hour
               user.save(function(err) {
                  if(err)
              {
                  console.log("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
                  return res.json("Sorry for inconvenience, your trial to reset the password has been denied");
              }
            done(err, token, user);
            });
          }
        });
        },

      // the next function actually sends the email with the reset url
        function(token, user, done) {
        // first login via our Gmail account, (this might be modified to use XOAuth2 later)
        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'Gmail',
        auth:
        {
            user: configAuth.gmail.user,
              pass: configAuth.gmail.pass
        }
      });
        // set the values of sender, receiver, subject and body of the mail
        var mailOptions = {
            to: user.email,
            from: 'fasa7ny.team@gmail.com',
            subject: 'Fasa7ny Password Reset',
            text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
            'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
            'http://' + req.headers.host + '/#!/auth/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +                                    //url containing the token generated
            'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
            };
          // send the email using nodeMailer, and previously specified options
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
                if(err)
            {
                    console.log("ERROR: can not send email to the entered email, please try again");
              return res.json("ERROR: can not send email to the entered email, please try again");
            }
            return res.json("An e-mail has been sent to " + user.email + " with further instructions.");
            done(err, 'done');
        });
        }
        ], function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        return res.redirect('http://localhost:8000');
      });
    }
},

    getReset: function(req, res) {
        var check = 0;

        console.log(req.param.token);

        // search the registeredusers collection
   User.findOne({ "local.resetPasswordToken": req.params.token,"local.resetPasswordExpires": { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
     if (!user) {
       console.log("nope");
      check++;
      if(check == 2)      // if no user found, print error msg and redirect
      {
        console.log('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.1');
      return res.json('Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      }
      }
      else
      {
      return  res.json({
        user: req.user,
        token: req.params.token
      });
    }
      });

        // check the validity of the token sent in the url
        // first search the business collection
        Business.findOne({ "local.resetPasswordToken": req.params.token, "local.resetPasswordExpires": { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, business){
        if(!business)
        {
          check++;
          if(check == 2)      // if no user found, print error msg and redirect
          {

          console.log('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.2');
          return res.json( 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');

          }
        }
        else
        {
          res.render('reset', {
          user: req.user,
          token: req.params.token
          });
        }
      });

    },

    postReset: function(req, res) {
  console.log("info " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  async.waterfall([
    // recheck the validity of the token sent (it might be expired)

    function(done) {
      var check = 0;
          Business.findOne({ "local.resetPasswordToken": req.params.token, "local.resetPasswordExpires": { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, business){
            console.log(1);
            if(!business)
            {
              check++;
              if(check == 2)
              {
              console.log('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
              return res.json('Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
              }
            }
            // save the new password, and reset token related attributes
            else
            {
               business.local.password = business.generateHash(req.body.password);
              business.local.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
              business.local.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
              business.save(function(err, business){
                 if(err)
                 {
                  console.log("error: can not update the password, please try again");
                  return res.json("error: can not update the password, please try again");
                 }
                 done(err, business);

              });
            }
          });
      User.findOne({ "local.resetPasswordToken": req.params.token, "local.resetPasswordExpires": { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
          console.log(2);
        if (!user) {

          console.log(req.params.token);
          check++;
              if(check == 2)
              {
              console.log('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
              return res.json('Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
              }
        }
        // save the new password, and reset token related attributes
        else
        {
        user.local.password = user.generateHash(req.body.password);
        user.local.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.local.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
        user.save(function(err,user) {
            if(err)
            {

             console.log("error: can not update the password, please try again");
             return res.json("error: can not update the password, please try again");

            }
            done(err, user);
        });
      }
      });
    },
   // send confirmation mail
    function(user, done) {
        var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service:'Gmail',
        auth:
        {
            user: configAuth.gmail.user,
            pass: configAuth.gmail.pass
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'passwordreset@demo.com',
        subject: 'Your password has been changed',
        text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
          'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        if(err)
        {
          console.log("ERROR: can not send email to the entered email, please try again");
          return res.redirect("ERROR: can not send email to the entered email, please try again");
        }
        return res.json('Success! Your password has been changed.');
        done(err);
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    res.redirect('http://localhost:8000/');
  });
},

getStripePK: function(req, res)
{
  return res.status(200).json(configAuth.stripe.publicKey);
}


}

module.exports = AuthController;
```